# Scrapy/Celery logging settings doesn't work

Tags: python, django, logging, scrapy, celery

I'm running Scrapy spider as a Celery task.

The problem is that Scrapy doesn't log into the file `scrapy.log`. It logs into the Celery log which. Moreover, I can see DEBUG levels inside Celery log and I don't know if it's because of celery settings or scrapy settings.

> [2017-07-17 05:49:20,848: WARNING/Process-4:1] 2017-07-17 05:49:20
>   [spider_1] INFO: Skipping telephone request...
>
> [2017-07-17 05:49:22,277: DEBUG/Process-4:1] Crawled (200) https://w...

I've set Celery logging level to info:

```
celery worker -A realestate_scanner -l info --logfile=logs/celery.log --purge
```

And I've set scrapy LOG_LEVEL and LOG_FILE in SCRAPY `settings.py`:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
LOG_FILE = django_dir+'/logs/scrapy.log'
```

The scrapy project is inside one of my Django app.

This is `celery.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'realestate_scanner.settings')
app = Celery('realestate_scanner')


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

And I have `Django` in DEBUG mode.

Do you know what to do? How to set celery loglevel to INFO and Scrapy to log to it's own file.

EDIT:

This is how I'm running the spider:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
handler = RotatingFileHandler(filename=__file__+'.log',maxBytes=64*64*64*64)
logger.addHandler(handler)

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=5))
def daily_scanning():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['LOG_FILE']='scrapy.log'
    logger.info('Scanning started') # this is also logged into celery.log
    job = Job(TopRealitySpider1())
    Processor().run(job)
    logger.info('Scanning stopped')
```

settings.py (django):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%y %b %d, %H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/celery.log',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        },
        'scrapy': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/scrapy.log'),
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'celery': {
            'handlers': ['celery', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'scrapy': {
            'handlers': ['scrapy'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    },

}

from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

RUN CELERY WORKER:

```
celery worker -A realestate_scanner -l info --logfile=logs/celery.log --purge # When I remove --logfile, everything goes into the console
```

START SHELL_PLUS:

```
>>> tasks.daily_scanning.delay()
```

RESULT:

One celery.log file:

> [2017-07-17 11:10:47,468: INFO/Process-1:1] Skipping telephone
>   request...
>
> [2017-07-17 11:10:47,468: WARNING/Process-1:1] 2017-07-17
>   11:10:47 [topreality_1] INFO: Skipping telephone request...
>
> [2017-07-17 11:10:48,680: DEBUG/Process-1:1] Crawled (200)

I've tried to do this (alfonsos answer):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy')
...
logger.debug('something')
```

Which works but native scrapy messages like "Crawled" are going into celery log.

I tried to do this in spider `__init__`:

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy')
```

which returns error (can't set attribute).

So there are two problems:
1. Celery logs DEBUG messages 
2. Scrapy logs into the celery.log

Comment: what happens if you remove the `--logfile=logs/celery.log` from the celery worker command?

Comment: Output goes to console. No scrapy.log too.

Comment: but logs/celery.log is created

Answer (score 1):

[alfonso.kim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149701/13823133) doesnt work because [django ignores all non **UPPERCASED** settings values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#creating-your-own-settings)
Spent many time to debug this

So, celery [will ignore uppercased settings since 6.0](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings)

But for now (version **5.2**) you need to ignore celery documentation and add uppercased settings value to your settings.py:

```
CELERY_WORKER_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

Celery won't [override logging configuration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#logging) after it

Don't forget to enable **CELERY_** workspace in **yourproject/celery.py**:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

After it, you can add [any of celery settings](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#configuration-directives) to your settings.py, but only in **UPPERCASE**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30869892)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but you can give it a chance.

It seems like celery is overriding the logging configuration. Since you are using it through Django, you can use it's [logging capabilities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/logging/):

in `settings.py`:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'scrapy': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs/scrapy.log'),
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'celery': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'scrapy': {
            'handlers': ['scrapy'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    }
}
```

and in scrapy:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('scrapy')
...
logger.debug('something')
```

finally, remove the `logfile` directive from the celery command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works partially. Yes I can create a logger which logs into this file but scrapy's native logger goes into celery log, moreover, celery seems to have DEBUG mode. I'm adding more information at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue.
found out that celery captures root logger output 
and logs them as debug

having this as my task solved my problem

```py
@app.task(name= "cralwer")
def crawler(spider):
    log_file = '/home/chamanmah/scrapyd/logs/pricewatch/'+spider+'/a.log'
    setting = get_project_settings()
    runner = CrawlerProcess(setting,install_root_handler=False)
    # crating file log handler
    fh =  logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file)
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # changing root log handeler that is <StreamHandler <stderr> (NOTSET)> before this line
    logging.getLogger().handlers = [fh]
    d = runner.crawl(spider)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

Celery is [overriding the logging configuration](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#logging).

Try:

```
CELERY_worker_hijack_root_logger=FALSE
```

For this to work you should enable `CELERY` as the namespace in `yourproject/celery.py`:

```
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't help. The same thing happens. Celery is logging everything including DEBUG level and Scrapy log is redirected to celery log.

Comment: Very strange. I have a django+celery application and it handles correctly the debug level in celery. Are you sure that you don't have a `celeryconfig.py` or something that is overriding the celery configuration?